# Google Filestore: Recommended limit 500 clients

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

According to this article:
https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/limits

Google suggests that the limit to the number of clients filestore is mounted on is 500.
Does anyone have details on why this limit is imposed? Is it just a hardware limit before we would notice performance degradation?

Suppose a container has 3 mounts to the same filestore, is that considered 3 clients or 1?

Answer (score 0):

The limits on the page you shared are "divided" between the categories you mention:

- Hardware limit: You can create files of up to 16 TB on Cloud Filestore fileshares.
- Performance: We recommend limiting the number of clients a Cloud Filestore fileshare is mounted on to 500.

Basically to recognize them, you can guide yourself on the way they are presented. The first one is a hard limit, and the second one is a "recommendation".

As for what is considered as a client, usually clients are the vms/clusters that you mounted to Filestore. I do not know why you would mount the Filestore to the same container 3 times, but it should count as a single client.

Hope you find this useful!